# Do PCBs have schematics? Revision

Tags: power-electronics

So the [responses](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/354665/8713) I received about schematics for PCBs were about what I expected.  I have a reel to reel recorder from the 1960's that was my grandfather's. Inside is a complete schematic for the solid state electronics. Much simpler back then and I think more interest in the consumer to understand how to fix what they bought.

I understand electronics are much more complicated these days, but a lot of the same components are still being used and in the same ways.  I work in the HVAC/R industry and following wiring diagrams often lead me back to some kind of control board that has a few test points, but beyond that I can only determine whether the problem is somewhere else or in the board somewhere.

I understand schematics and have been studying electronics as a hobby, but I can't figure out how to understand a PCB, like I can understand the wiring in a mechanical system.  There doesn't seem to be any plans available.

- A diagram for the board traces to each component.
- A list of components and their values.

I mean it seems to me to be the same thing as the wiring for a walk-in freezer really. It's just all the wiring and components are on something you can hold in your hand and not spanning across a building.  How can I best amalgamate the two?

Comment: Of course the PCB has schematics, but "No user serviceable parts inside."

Comment: Could you *please* parse your wall of text into paragraphs, with the questions at the end. Avoid idle speculation as it does us no good.

Comment: A Printed Circuit Board has conductive copper tracks on the board that serve the same function (and make the same connections) as the wires in a hand-wired circuit do.  There should be little difficulty relating a simple two-sided PCB to its schematic.  Relating a multi-layer PCB to its schematic will be somewhat more difficult, as you can't see the connections on the inner layers.

Comment: Thanks sparky.  I'm a nuts and bolt guy but i will try to work on my linguistics. Could you try to control your snide remarks as they do no one  but yourself any good.

Comment: PCBs don't have random layout if that's what you're asking... there are tools and software to create where everything goes on a PCB.... EDIT: To expand what Sparky was trying to say. He's just trying to make this website look neat so that other people can refer to it and it's easier to read. It's a little unbearable when everything is in a single paragraph and you can lose your location when you read something from a single paragraph.

Comment: Gotca. I will try to fomat my inquiries better.

Comment: However, and to get back on topic, PCB schematics aren't helpful unless you're the one putting the parts onto the PCB. If you're trying to read a layout of how an electronic works, you should ask about the engineer about the schematic drawing so that you can see everything in fine detail.

Comment: I imagine the engineer in question might be a bit creaky

Comment: search for the service manual

Comment: https://www.hifiengine.com/hfe_downloads/index.php?sony/sony_tc-530_service.pdf

Comment: I indented my paragraphs on the edit but its not showing on the post. Christ, i feel like I'm  in an English class!

Comment: Anyway I'm done with that. Thanks for any help. Goodnight.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a reel to reel recorder from the 1960's that was my grandfather's. Inside is a complete schematic for the solid state electronics.
>   [...]
>   I understand electronics are much more complicated these days, but a lot of the same components are still being used and in the same ways.

I respectfully disagree that "a lot of the same components are still being used and in the same ways". Many (most?) modern systems use components that are different from the 1960s. Changes like increased integration (e.g. from discrete components into ICs), component technology improvements, and the addition of firmware / microcode in programmable parts, make modern devices very different from the often off-the-shelf parts used in the 1960s consumer goods.

> I understand schematics and have been studying electronics as a hobby, but I can't figure out how to understand a PCB, like I can understand the wiring in a mechanical system.

Some of that understanding comes with experience (a well-laid out PCB practically "shouts" its functional blocks at you - just look at *good* teardown videos) but for a *detailed* understanding you often need additional information.

> There doesn't seem to be any plans available.
>
> - A diagram for the board traces to each component.
> - A list of components and their values.

That information *is* available (it's needed by the original designer to create & build the PCB in the first place) but often it's only available within the original company, and perhaps also some approved repair companies.

As others have said, the closest you might get would be a service manual, although their availability seems to be diminishing generally e.g. as the "time to market" shortens (so less time is available for people to write documentation) and cost reduction pressures affect manufacturer's cost/benefit analysis of providing that information.

The use of programmable parts (e.g. microcontrollers) sometimes makes the repair process much more complicated, if "field replacement" of the programmable parts was never expected. There simply may not be a documented process for programming a new blank MCU (or other programmable component) outside of the factory, apart from on the designer's desk. (Of course if you could obtain the required binary files, then additional options become possible, but again, those files may not be released outside of the original manufacturer.)

You could try reverse-engineering the PCBs where you want to better understand their operation (and I've done plenty of that over the years, as have some other people here on EE.SE). However that can be a long process for complex boards, requiring test equipment and datasheets for as many components as possible. It can also be made more difficult if important components have "house markings" (i.e. non-standard part numbers) or no markings at all.

Having worked in parts of companies where initially I *didn't* have access to component-level service manuals, and was later promoted to positions where I *did* have access to full design documentation, I've seen a number of reasons why that level of detail isn't always distributed to installers & field service engineers.

I could explain some of those reasons I've seen, but that won't help you if the manufacturer has definitely made the decision not to provide the level of information you're requesting. :-(

Also, even if you got a diagram showing (for example) IC "A" pin 4 connected to IC "B" pin 10, with a 2.2uF capacitor from that signal to ground, that would usually be little help without some narrative / explanation about *why* that design choice had been made, and what good & bad signals from IC "A" would look like. That explanation might only exist in the designer's head, and might not be available in *any* documentation at all.

Therefore getting a "diagram for the board traces to each component" (as you mentioned) might still require you to reverse-engineer the *reasons* for that design and measure the expected circuit behaviour, in order to create your own service manual from the "bare" diagram, before it is any use for troubleshooting. Given enough time and enough test equipment that's "do-able", but it can be a long process (been there, done that).

You said:

> I understand schematics and have been studying electronics as a hobby

One possibility could be that you are simply not the "expected audience" of the HVAC manufacturer. If *most* of the installers/repairers are only capable of following simple wiring diagrams, and are *not* capable of following electronic schematics (unlike you), then there is a good incentive for the manufacturer *not* to waste time/money producing documentation which the "expected audience" wouldn't (couldn't) use.

Ultimately the answer remains the same: You (and other HVAC/R engineers working on the same type of equipment) can only use the information which is available to you, or which you create through reverse-engineering - even if having more detail would allow you to do more in-depth problem-solving.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have no idea what documents exist as they are not made public and your best bet is the service manual which has everything one would need to navigate.

e.g. [image]